# Python for and if loop for categorize

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 columns in a dataframe (both strings), and a separate list.

```
      name   id
0     wine     2
1     beer     4
2     cheese   6
3     yogurt   8
4     choc     10
5     whisky   12

list = ["beers","wines","whiskies","chocolates and candy","cheeses","yogurts"]
```

I want to compare the list and the column "name", and make a new column as "category" that will be one of the list

expected output:

```
      name   id   category
0     wine     2   wines
1     beer     4   beers
2     cheese   6   cheeses
3     yogurt   8   yogurts
4     choc     10  chocolates and candy
5     whisky   12  whiskies
```

I started with something like this

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

for i in df["name"]:
    for x in subcategory:
        z = similar(i,x)
        if z >= 0.60:
```

but didn´t know what I can do, got blocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use pandas, you might as well make use of its capabilities (vectorization, that is).

```py
# note: do not use builtin names like 'list' as variable names
categories = ["beers", "wines", "whiskies", "chocolates and candy", "cheeses", "yogurts"]

def get_category(cat, f):
    return max(categories, key=lambda x: f(cat, x))

df['category'] = df['name'].apply(get_category, f=similar)
```

With your `similar`-function it returns "cheeses" for "choc", but the nice thing about this approach (apart from the fact that it's way faster and more concise than `iterrows`) is you can put any similarity-function you like and try out different metrics, e.g., [fuzzy string matching](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) might be an option here: `partial_ratio` gives the right result for your example:

```
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
>>> df['category'] = df['name'].apply(get_category, f=fuzz.partial_ratio)
>>> df
     name  id              category
0    wine   2                 wines
1    beer   4                 beers
2  cheese   6               cheeses
3  yogurt   8               yogurts
4    choc  10  chocolates and candy
5  whisky  12              whiskies
```

Comment: This one helped me a lot, thank you so much, but I have a question, do you know if this can be made with Spanish words?

Comment: I can't promise it will be 100% right in all cases, but it certainly works for Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to create a new column based on some logic.

I quickly typed this code below, which shows you how to implement logic for adding a new dataframe column. It probably is not the fastest/cleanest solution but will most likely be the easiest method to see what is happening.

```
import pandas as pd

sampledata = {'name': ['wine', 'beer', 'cheese', 'yoghurt'], 'id': [2, 4, 6, 8]}  

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=sampledata)

newcolum = []

for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    #Do your logic here:
    if row["name"] == "wine":
        newcolum.append("wines")
    else:
        newcolum.append("not wines") 

dataframe["category"] = newcolum

print(dataframe.head())
```

output:

```
      name  id   category
0     wine   2      wines
1     beer   4  not wines
2   cheese   6  not wines
3  yoghurt   8  not wines
```

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['wine', 2], ['beer', 4,], ['cheese', 6, ]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', ])
```

---

```
df['Similarity'] = 0
df['Category'] = 0
```

---

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

    for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
        for x in list:
            z = similar(row['a'],x)
            if z >= 0.60: 
                df.loc[index, "Similarity"] = z
                df.loc[index, "Category"] = x
```

result:

[image]